# Css for print content break down in two pages

Tags: css, printing

I need to print some database content in multiple pages.

When i have a large text, and it's occupies two pages, the text on second page should start after 3cm from the top and not at the edge of the page.

Any sugestion?

```
@media print {

@page {
    margin: 0;
}

body  {
    margin: 2cm 3cm 2cm 3cm ;
    font: 12pt Arial;
}

}
```

Comment: can you share the screenshot of the problem or the code snippet

Comment: Please add more information and also your html thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the margins in the `@page` rule, not in the rule for `body`, like

```
@media print {
    @page  { 
        margin-top: 20mm;
        margin-bottom: 20mm;
        margin-left: 30mm;
        margin-right: 30mm;
    }
...
```

Comment: What you said has logic, but, in that way, it appears url and page number on header/footer.

Comment: that's a browser setting (and can be deactivated in most browsers) - you don't have any influence on that via the website code

Comment: you're absolutely corretc. Thanks.